# Building a Drupal My Favorites/My Subscriptions Block

Tags: drupal, subscriptions

I have a site where I want to do something with the subscriptions module.

First, I'd like to use the subscriptions module to let users pick things they'd like to track/subscribe to.  I'd then like to also allow them to see their subscriptions in a block that displays something like the "Last 10" or a listing of subscriptions with a count of articles or something like that.

Any suggestions on what to use to put this together?  Is the Subscriptions module a good starting point?

Comment: If the FLAG module is used, it looks like this subscribes to a node.  Does it work if I use it for a thread like a BLOG or BOOK, flagging new nodes as they are added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put this together with the Flag and Views modules. Requires minimal setup.